# Maximizing trapezoid area

Tags: derivatives

Find the trapezoid of largest area that can be inscribed in the region bound by the graph of $y=4-x^2$, and the $x$-axis.

So, I know that you need to maximize the area of the trapezoid, which I used     $A=\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot h$, but I only know to guess and check.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone with sufficient rep, [this is the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219454/mathematical-induction-with-capital-pi) that was deleted.

Comment: @crash Since the question was unanswered, it's entirely up to the user to delete it. If you'd like to answer it, just ask and answer.

Comment: @pizza I highly doubt that would be well-received--it would simply look like a silly attempt to garner rep for no reason. The OP was active while I made my comments and during his/her original post. Why the person refuses to respond is beyond me. I think it's perfectly reasonable to be annoyed/frustrated to have a question deleted after spending a number of minutes typing up a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ther vertices of the trapezoid lie in $$A=(2,0),\;B=(-2,0),\;C=(-x,4-x^2),\;D=(x,4-x^2)$$
we have:
$$[ABCD] = f(x) = (2+x)(4-x^2)=(2+x)^2(2-x) $$
and since $f'(x)=(2+x)(2-3x)$ the maximum of the area occurs for $x=\frac{3}{2}$:
$$ [ABCD] \leq \frac{49}{8}.$$

Comment: How did you get f'?

Comment: @RachelBray: I computed it. Since $x=-2$ is a double root for $f(x)$, $(x+2)$ is a divisor of $f'(x)$. We also know that $f'(x)=-3x^2+\ldots$, since $f(x)=-x^3+\ldots$. Since $f'(0)=[x]f(x) = 4$ it follows that $f'(x)=(x+2)(2-3x)$.